# Time-stepper approach to eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues, arpack

For a linear system

$$
M \dot{u} = Au \qquad \textrm{or} \qquad \dot{u} = L u
$$

The **generalized** eigenvalue problem is
$$
A e = \lambda M e
$$

We can use the *time-stepper* approach which essentially computes the eigenvalues of the operator

$$
E = \exp(L T)
$$

If $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $E$ then it is related to the original eigenvalue by

$$
\mu = \exp(\lambda T)
$$
and $T$ has to be chosen appropriately. If I have a code $E_{\Delta} \approx E$ which solves the initial value problem, then I can couple this to ARPACK to compute the eigenvalues. I would use the **standard** eigenvalue solver of ARPACK on the operator $E_\Delta$.

But I would also like to use the inner product induced by $M$ in the Arnoldi process so that the eigenvectors have unit norm in the inner product of $M$. How can I achieve this with ARPACK ?

Comment: Have you asked the authors of ARPACK?

Comment: I think instead of solving $E_\Delta e = \mu e$, I can solve the generalized eigenvalue problem $ M E_\Delta e = \mu M e$. Then ARPACK will automatically use the correct inner product.

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated. Why don't you just normalize the vectors after they are returned by ARPACK?